# Is there a jQuery plugin for progress bar

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

Is there a jQuery plugin for a progress bar, such that the length of that bar depends on a number and as the number become smaller, the length becomes shorter and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a [progress bar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar). Include the relevant parts of JQuery UI, and simply do:

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 42 });
```

This will turn a `<div id="progressbar"></div>` into a almost half (42 %) colored progress bar.

Answer (score 2):

It's included in jqueryui http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.dumpsterdoggy.com/articles/?jquery-horizontal-bar-graph). It is a simple article that it will do what you want.

[6 jQuery Chart Plugins For Your App](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/6-jquery-chart-plugins-reviewed/) presents 6 fully featured plug-ins.